# Читалка для .djvu

Tags: поиск-программ

Подскажите, пожалуйста, это. Вообще, моя любимая читалка этого формата - Irfanview. Я и этот формат полюбил через эту программу. А в программе привлекает то, что одну и ту же книгу можно открыть в скольки угодном количестве окон. Однако, когда настраивал программу Asymptote, пришлось установить ghostscript и с тех пор все испортилось.  Вот как сейчас:

[image]

Слева книга открыта в Irfanview - как видно, буквы стали нечеткими. А справа - та же страница той же книгй в другой читалке. Как видно, все буквы четкие. Не подскажите читалку для .djvu в которой **одну и ту же книгу можно было бы открыть хоть сколько раз**?

Comment: Что значит "открыть хоть сколько раз"? Вообще, попробуйте sumatra pdf

Comment: @insolor программа может делать блокирующее открытие документа (share read), что не позволяет открыть его на разных страницах одновременно.

Comment: @insolor, это значит открыть одну и ту же книгу в одной и той же программе в независимых друг от друга окнах. И этих окон может быть хоть сколько.